# How often is the room cleaned on average? (Stochastic/Probability question)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

If the last time Bob cleaned up his room was $k$ days ago, then he cleans it up today with probability $1/(k + 1)$. But if the last time he cleaned up was 4 days ago, his father cleans it up. How often is the room cleaned on average?

I'm not really sure what to do for this question and have been stuck for a while. Would anyone be able to help out?

Comment: Is the first sentence "if the last time *Bob* cleaned up his room" or "if the last time Bob's room was cleaned up (by him or his father)?"

Comment: The former I believe!

Comment: your problem is either a 'trick problem' or broken.  There's also potentially more linguistic issues.  You've written "Bob cleaned up... But if the last time he cleaned up was 4 days ago, his father cleans it up."  This reads that the father only cleans when Bob last did it 4 days ago, *not* when someone did it 4 days ago.  The expected time until Bob cleans is $\infty$ which gives a null recurrent chain. And the percent of time the room is cleaned by Bob or his dad tends to zero.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is plainly to figure out what the states are.  We have $C_k$ for $k=1,2,3$ meaning that the room was last cleaned $k$ days ago.  We also have two absorbing states, $B$ and $F$, meaning that Bob or his father cleans the room, respectively.  We know that the initial state is $C_1$.

If the chain is in state $C_k,\ k=1,2$ then it moves to state $B$ with probability $1/(k+1)$ and to state $C_{i+1}$ with probability $k/(k+1)$.  If it is in state $C_3$ then it moves to state $F$ with probability $3/4$.

Now you can find the probability of states $B$ and $F$ by analyzing the [absorbing Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain). But this is overkill.  No state is ever re-visited, so you can just draw a tree diagram.

Answer (score 0):

**1st interpretation**
There's basically two ways to solve this.  I only show the longer way because the problem breaks / involves a null recurrent chain.

*Longer way*
$P = \pmatrix{
q_1 & p_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
q_2 & 0 & p_2& 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
q_3 & 0 & 0 & p_3 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
q_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_4 & 0 & \dots\\
q_5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_5 & \dots\\
q_6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots}$

where $q_k = \frac{1}{1+k}$
while longer, this is standard /canonical matrix for renewal processes on the natural numbers known as an **Age** matrix, so this is worth learning.  The steady state probability of being in state one is given by $\frac{1}{\mu}$ where $\mu$ is the expected time of an epoch (expected time until visiting state 1 again given a start in state 1)
$\mu = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty\big(\prod_{j=1}^k p_j\big) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty Pr\{X\gt k\} $

But this telescopes

$\mu = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty\big(\prod_{j=1}^k p_j\big) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty\big(\prod_{j=1}^k \frac{k}{k+1}\big)= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k+1} = \infty $

i.e. we recover the harmonic series. This means  $P^k \to \mathbf 0$. (We can actually calculate and show the chain is null recurrent not transient,  but this isn't needed here).

So the answer would be that the room is cleaned every time state 1 or 4 is visited but the time averaged amount that occurs is zero because this isn't a positive recurrent chain.